# How to play MP4 videos stored on assets folder on Android 1.5?

Tags: android, mp4

Ineed to play a short MP4 video on my android app I'm searching info about how to load mp4 videos but i can't find the way to do it on Android 1.5. My app sould be compatible from Android 1.5 to 4.0

I tryed with a lot of tutorials from google, but none of them works. For example, now i'm trying with the VideoViewDemo from android developers: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html

I have a video on my ASSETS folder, and i just need to play the video, only this. I can not believe that doesn't exists a simple and quick way to do it.

Please, if someone knows how to do it i will apreciate your help a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the video in the raw folder instead and construct a URI like this:

```
android.resource://[package]/[resource_id]
android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]
```

For example:

```
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android:resource://com.my.package/"+R.raw.myVideo);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
```

Comment: i need to load the video from assets folder, not for raw. Please can you tell me how to load it from assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at page 314 of Mark's Busy Coder's guide to Android:
http://commonsware.com/Android/Android-1_0-CC.pdf

There is an example there on how to get something from the asset folder.

Also, make sure that the codec is H.264 (not H.264 AVC).  I don't think AVC was supported in 1.5.  See:  http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Happy coding!

Comment: the problem is not only to load the video from assets... the problem is that i just can't play it, i'm trying to make working the example of the question but the video doesn't play, i really need a full working example of code that can play mp4 videos :S

Comment: i checked the way of the book, "file:///android_asset/1.mp4"  and this way doesnt works :(