# How to Play mp4 videos from Asset Folder Android 11?

Tags: android

**Hi All I am new to Android, I tried accessing Images from Access Folder Android Its works Fine. Below is the Code.**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_picturedetail, container, false);
    Bundle b = getArguments();
    Drawable d;
    am = getActivity().getAssets();
    PictDictDetails pd = (PictDictDetails) b.getSerializable("pictobj");
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iv_picture);
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_picture_name);
    String path = pd.getPath();
    String name = pd.getName();
    try
    {
        InputStream ims = am.open(path);
        d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        iv.setImageDrawable(d);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Now I am Trying to Play Video in VideoView with exact Same Logic BUt it is not working 
Please Find the below Code, and help me out where i am wrong?
Appreciate your help.**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.videofragment, container, false);
    Bundle b = getArguments();
    // Drawable d;
    am = getActivity().getAssets();
    PictDictDetails pd = (PictDictDetails) b.getSerializable("pictobj");
    VideoView iv = (VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.iv_video);
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_picture_name);
    String path = pd.getPath();
    String name = pd.getName();

    SurfaceHolder holder = iv.getHolder();
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setDisplay(holder);
    //AssetFileDescriptor afd;

    try
    {
        //InputStream ims = am.open(path);
        // d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        //iv.setImageDrawable(d);

        // AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = am.openFd(path);
        // long start = descriptor.getStartOffset();
        // long end = descriptor.getLength();

        /// mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),descriptor.getStartOffset(),descriptor.getLength());
        // MediaController mediaController= new MediaController();
        // mediaController.setAnchorView(iv);
        // iv.setMediaController(mediaController);
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = am.openFd(path);
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        player.prepareAsync();
        player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261733/how-to-play-mp4-videos-stored-on-assets-folder-on-android-1-5)

Answer (score 1):

```
**I have Found a Solution, Confirm if it works for anyone.**
 player = new MediaPlayer();
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("video_file.mp4");
    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength()); 
    player.setDisplay(_holder); //_holder is SurfaceHolder of SurfaceView
    player.prepare();
```

Answer (score 0):

***Notes :***

1) You have to copy the video into your project's res/raw folder not in asset.

2) The supported format (3gp, wmv, mp4 ) and named with lower case, numerics, underscores and dots in its filename: **video_file.mp4**

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView)
String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
videoView.start();
```

You can use activity helper method `getPackageName()` which can be used by your code when constructing the correct URI to your video.

Comment: Hi What is the getPackageName()? How to use it? I am new to Android. I am using SQLlite to Map Video files path. Please can u edit my code and share . I am Using asset manager i have more than 100 videos.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName%28%29...you can call it any where inside an activity.

Comment: What will be the path if i change to res/raw folder ? Eg while Accessing images i am directly accessing path pictures/category/sunflower.jpg

Comment: it is an requirement and it does not matter if app exceed 150MB.

Comment: It is must needed for me. I have heard in res/raw we can use we have to play single file. There is only asset folder option if we have to play multiple files from database. If you know pls help. There is a solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562954/using-large-number-of-videos-in-android-application

Comment: dont want that much it cover in 100 videos in 50 mb

Comment: Dear Anoop, There is a Solution using APK file expansions http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.in/2013/01/apk-expansion-files-in-android-with.html

Comment: what about asset folder?